# How can I convert Cyrillic stored as LATIN1 ( sql ) to true UTF8 Cyrillic with iconv?

Tags: sql, character-encoding, iconv

I have a SQL dump file consisting of incorrectly stored Cyrillic Russian ( WINDOWS-1251 ) text, example `Èðàíñêèå` which should properly be displayed as `Иранские`.

In the past I have successfully converted the sql file but memory fails in what I did and in what order.

Logically it would make sense that since it's stored in LATIN1 I would convert from LATIN1 to WINDOWS-1251 and then from WINDOWS-1251 to UTF-8//TRANSLIT or something like that.

So far I've tried:

## 1.

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT -o new.sql snippet.sql
```

Output:

`Г€Г°Г Г­Г±ГЄГЁГҐ` ( Not what I want )

## 2.

```
iconv -f LATIN1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT -o new.sql snippet.sql
```

Output:

`Ã<88>Ã°Ã Ã­Ã±ÃªÃ¨Ã¥` ( Not what I want either )

**Notes**

- It's possible that I might have converted once and then twice to get my desired result, but I'm pretty sure that on the last step I converted from `WINDOWS-1251` to `UTF-8//TRANSLIT` as that was written down in my notes.
- One other note is that I'm viewing `Èðàíñêèå` in the SQL file when the file encoding is utf8 ( native in vim ). If I do `set enc=latin1` in vim then I see `~Hð| íñêèå` as if that doesn't make it more confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 < in.sql | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 > out.sql
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you. Although I did have to replace around ~40-50 or so UTF8 characters with a temporary string indicating the Unicode hexpoint since iconv could not process without those, it did work out.

Comment: Actually it seems I forgot to specify `//TRANSLIT` in the initial iconv, should've done that instead.