# How to convert a window-1251 (russian cyrillic) MySql Database to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a databse of a russsian website and it's encoded in windows-1251. Another words, the letters look like this from phpmyadmin: `Âûõîäÿùàÿ â Ëîíäîíå ãàçåòà íà àðàáñêîì ÿçûêå «Àëü-Õàéÿò» ñîîáùèëà,`. Another words illegible characters. In order to display the content properly this code must be added in php.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

I would like to migrate this site an opensource software such as joomla or wordpress without hiccups.

So, in order to do that I need to convert these funny looking characters to utf-8 which will look like this even in phpmyadmin:

```
Выходящая в Лондоне газета на арабском языке «Аль-Хайят» сообщила,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dump the `.sql` and use `iconv` ( linux program ).

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 < in.sql | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 > out.sql
```

I did this earlier this year, [How can I convert Cyrillic stored as LATIN1 ( sql ) to true UTF8 Cyrillic with iconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396376/how-can-i-convert-cyrillic-stored-as-latin1-sql-to-true-utf8-cyrillic-with-ic)

If you dont know how to get iconv, and dont have any sensitive information stored in the sql, I can do it for you and send it back to you.

Comment: Hi meder, the info is not that sensitive, however the size of sql dump file is 180 mg. I'm going to try your suggestion. The only problem I have is that the original database is stored on a paid hosting account where I don't have access to shell command. I have a linux server for testing purposes. So what do i need to do with the sql dump file once I've exported it  via phpmyadmin from the paid hosting account?

Comment: I get an error 'iconv: illegal input sequence at position 6721'

Comment: Oh, I forgot.. you need to do a replace for weird characters you run into, replace it with a caps lock version of what it is, like 'THISISACURLYQUOTE' and do a replace on entire document, then after u run iconv, replace 'THISISACURLYQUOTE' with it since it will be UTF8. Do that for every character you run into.

Comment: I have no idea how to replace weird characters with a caps lock version. P.S. how do know when someone adds a comment. I refresh the page every few minutes. Is there a notification setting in stackoverflow that I missed?

Comment: Do you know how to replace "foo" with "bar" in a text file? Same concept pretty much.

Comment: I got it. But which weird characters do I need to replace with the caps lock version?

Comment: I'm sorry for asking a stupid question. How do I find where position 6721 is?

Comment: it's the 6721st character from the first character in your text file.

Comment: meder, thanks to your advice I was able to do something I thought was impossible. I converted a database of 29000 records to utf8. I was searching the internet for days. Actually there were about 5 characters that couldn't be converted so I replaced them with codes that I can remember for later to change them back after conversion. A million thanks to you!