# MySQL - export DB with cyrillic fails

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export my DB, but I am getting some kind of error. When I try to export, I get following result (this is example of exported data):

```
**VALUES
(1, 'Đ›ĐľĐşĐ°Đ»Đ˝Đ° ĐˇĐ°ĐĽĐľŃĐżŃ€Đ°Đ˛Đ°', **
```

DB and all the fields have utf8_general_ci collation. What is going on here? Is there a way to fix this?

When I use **SHOW CREATE TABLE**, I get this:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
 `id_page` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title_srb` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `title_eng` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `page_srb` longtext NOT NULL,
 `page_eng` longtext,
 `slug_srb` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `slug_eng` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `viewed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_page`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Collation is one thing, encoding is another. What is your encoding?

Comment: Where can I check that? (I am not very good with MySQL...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql

Comment: @Sasha: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219850/how-to-convert-a-window-1251-russian-cyrillic-mysql-database-to-utf-8

Comment: @matcheek I added result for show create table.