# sql: converting from cp1251 to utf8

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, converters, character-set

How to compile a SQL query that converts the table column from **cp1251 to utf8**. My database and all the tables in it with the encoding of utf8, but the information inside on cp1251. Because of this information is displayed incorrectly. A simple change of the encoding in the settings turns them into other incomprehensible symbols. I tried to change `DEFAULT CHARESET` in the dump, but it did not help either :( Maybe there are other methods?

**Part of the database:**

[image]

I did so:

1. *mysqldump -u mysql -p conference_db --allow-keywords --create-options --complete-insert --default-character-set=utf8 --add-drop-table > dump.sql*
2. All ... *DEFAULT CHARESET=utf8* changed to ... *DEFAULT CHARESET=cp1251* (in CREATE TABLE)
3. *mysql -u mysql -p conference_db --default-character-set=cp1251 < dump.sql*

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to do this with dump and restore operations.

However, you can convert the character set of the offending column in a SELECT statement using the [CONVERT operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert): `CONVERT(column USING utf8)`

For example, if you have a new empty table with the correct character set on the column, this will copy the old table to the new and do the conversion.

```
 INSERT INTO new_table
 SELECT journal_id, locale, setting_name, 
        CONVERT(setting_value USING utf8) setting_value
        setting_type
   FROM table
```

Comment: Thx! But it does not help.=( The fact is that the column already has encoding utf8. But the text inside resembles cp1251. And every time I try to use transforming functions, they take this text for utf8.

Answer (score 0):

The *default* charset on a table does not matter.  What matters is the charset on the string columns.

Back up to the original; I worry that the failed conversion has only made things worse, and more difficult to untangle.

The screenshot looks a lot like "Mojibake".  (If you can paste the data in your Question, I can analyze it further.)  See "Mojibake" in [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for what mistakes cause it.

For help in recovering the data, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT HEX(col) ...` so we can see what you have.  ("column from cp1251" is ambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but I had the same problem in 2022 and this thread was the first in google results.

This answer worked for me: [How can I convert Cyrillic stored as LATIN1 ( sql ) to true UTF8 Cyrillic with iconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396376/how-can-i-convert-cyrillic-stored-as-latin1-sql-to-true-utf8-cyrillic-with-i)

And if you stumble on `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 113498`
then you can replace invalid character(s) with command

```
printf '-' | dd bs=1 seek=113498 conv=notrunc of=<your file with errors>
```

this will put hyphen instead of invalid character.

Or you can ignore invalid characters by adding "-c" to iconv:

```
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t latin1 < input.sql | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 > output.sql
```